# How to use IF or IFNA or OR to get a value from multiple columns?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, excel-2019

I have 4 columns in **Excel** with values

[image]

as mentioned in the image. I want to get the output in column E. The output should come from each row with a `Not Null` value. For eg Row 1 should return 1 as that is the only value from `column A and Row 1` which is not null, similarly Row 2 should return 2 from column B which is not null and rest of the other values are and so forth. I am expecting an output as

[image].

I created some formulas but they are returning only the value form the last part of `if` condition.

`=IF(ISNA(A1),B1,IF(ISNA(B1),C1,IF(ISNA(C1),D1,IF(ISNA(D1),A1,D1) )))`

`=IF(ISNA(D1),A1,IF(ISNA(C1),D1,IF(ISNA(B1),C1,IF(ISNA(A1),B1,A1))))`

`=IF(ISNA(C1),A1,IF(ISNA(D1),B1,IF(ISNA(B1),D1,IF(ISNA(C1),A1,C1))))`

`=IF(ISNA(D1),B1,IF(ISNA(C1),A1,IF(ISNA(A1),C1,IF(ISNA(B1),D1,B1))))`

They are not returning the result as I expected, is there a way to have a combined formula, to get the value from row which is `Not Null` in a separate column.

Comment: Is `NULL` the literal text "NULL", or a custom format of a `#N/A!` error? Because in the first case I wouldn't expect `ISNA(B1)` to return `TRUE`.

Comment: Please consider it as custom format `#N/A!` error.